# Magento2 category page exception log "category.product.type.details.renderers"

Tags: magento2

I am getting this error in category page. It does not display any product.
In exception log, I found this error:

> Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException : The element "category.product.type.details.renderers " already has a child : " configurable "

If I set simple product in category, it is working, but if I set configurable product, it does not render any product in category page.

How to fix this error?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it cant be reproduced and there was no reply since month.

Comment: i am getting the same problem in magento 2.1.8

Answer (score 3):

Your exception means that the element -`category.product.type.details.renderers` may has two children with the same name. One of them is declared in this xml file - 
`vendor/magento/module-swatches/view/frontend/layout/catalog_category_view.xml`. The second may is your custom module.

Comment: I dont have custom module, I have theme and this is working fine and I setup with second server and I found this problem in category page same source and db.

Comment: You build two sites with the same DB?

Comment: I had this problem with Ortho/Tizzy template. After removing duplicate from file `app/design/frontend/Ortho/tizzy/Ortho_Featuredproduct/layout/default.xml` everything works fine.